# SVG: How to programmatically center an <Text/> based on <Rect/> position and size

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I've made this sudoku board on Figma

[image]

and I want to put this on my website using ReactJS. My goal is to add events listeners to the rects and change the value based on user pressing 1-9 numbers (just like sudoku works). The problems is that I don't know how to programmatically position `text` based on `rect` (x,y) position and size.

For example:

```
<g x="7.49219" y="4.37108" width="34.8721" height="34.8721">
       <rect
            x="7.49219"
            y="4.37108"
            width="34.8721"
            height="34.8721"
            rx="4.75"
            stroke="#D5D5D5"
            stroke-width="0.5"
       />
       <text id="text_test" fill="red" fontSize={24}>
           5
       </text>
</g>
```

I've calculated the text position as

```
x = rectXPos + (rectWidth / 2)

y = rectYPos + (rectHeight / 2)
```

but it gives me:

[image]

I thought considering the text width and height in the formula to center it. But I just get the text size in pixels on the browser

[image]

So when I try to update the formula to

```
x = rectXPos + (rectWidth / 2) - (textWidth / 2)

y = rectYPos + (rectHeight / 2) + (textHeight / 2)
```

I get this:

[image]

The X position works but the Y don't.

1. What am I missing?
2. Is there a better way to implement what I want?

Comment: Do you have to use an SVG? Laying the grid out with HTML and CSS would be much easier.

Comment: Use `text-anchor="middle"` and `text-anchor="middle"` for the text as attributes or css

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Well I kinda want to learn how to work with SVG, but if it seems to be a bad option for this case so I'll change to HTML only

Comment: @enxaneta it doesn't work, it aligns the text to the SVG center, and I have to align based on rect

Comment: you are using the calculated center of the rect as x and y attributes for the text

Comment: @enxaneta Yeah!

Comment: This looks like an obvious use for grids within a grid and flex positioning the text centrally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange the text element with the attributes `text-anchor="middle"` and `dominant-baseline="middle"` and set the position the middle of the expected "frame". So, in this case the `<rect>` and the `<text>` have the same starting point. The `<rect>` is 40x40 and then the `<text>` needs to be in 20,20.

You can see from the example that you can use `<g>` and its attribute transform/translate to move around the elements. This gives mush more readable code now that you have 9x9 elements that need to be placed.

If this is going to be used in a browser I will suggest you to use CSS for styling. Like replace the attribute `stroke` etc. with a stylesheet like:

```
svg.sudoku rect {
  stoke: #D5D5D5;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <g transform="translate(5 5)">
    <g transform="translate(0 0)">
      <rect
        width="40"
        height="40"
        rx="4.75"
        stroke="#D5D5D5"
        stroke-width="0.5"
        fill="none"
        />
      <text x="20" y="20" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" fill="red" font-size="20">5</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(45 0)">
      <rect
        width="40"
        height="40"
        rx="4.75"
        stroke="#D5D5D5"
        stroke-width="0.5"
        fill="none"
        />
      <text x="20" y="20" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" fill="red" font-size="20">2</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```